# C#.net Inline Databinder convert datetime to string with formatting

Tags: c#, .net, date, data-binding

I have a nested repeater that I want to convert the databound object

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"myDate") %>
```

to a date format of "MM/dd/yy".  I have tried

`<%# string.Format(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"myDate").ToString(),"MM/dd/yyyy") %>` in multiple iterations ie`..(string)(Databinder....`  `string.Format((string)(DataBinder.Eval("myDate")),"MM/dd/yy")`

as well as 
`<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"myDate").ToString("MM/dd/yy") %>`  The last one give me an error that ToString() does not take an argument.  I have looked all over and have found nothing that works.  Any thoughts?

**ACTUAL CODE IN .net page (WebForm):**
`<label class="anj"><%# string.Format(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"myDate").ToString(),"MM/dd/yyyy") %> </label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "myDate", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy") %>
```

The reason your code with `String.Format` is failing is because you are trying to apply a date format on a string value, instead of `DateTime` type value.

Comment: I keep forgetting that format overload.  I tried this as well as {0:d} for short date with no luck.  I think the issue may be with the return value.   I will just have to change the sql to format the date prior to returning the resultset.  Thanks